# R functions not available after install from GitHub

Tags: r, github, r-package

I'm trying to create my first R package, basically following [this tutorial](https://hilaryparker.com/2014/04/29/writing-an-r-package-from-scratch/)

I've created the package and added it to [Github](https://github.com/nriddiford/cnvPlotteR).

Now I want to actually install it from GitHub and run it, here's what I see:

```
> install_github("nriddiford/cnvPlotteR")

Downloading GitHub repo nriddiford/cnvPlotteR@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/nriddiford/cnvPlotteR/zipball/master
Installing cnvPlotteR
'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  '/private/var/folders/fb/xk_7jg3s3sj4vc19hbjz92900000gn/T/RtmpN7J2Qt/devtools149042e0f3cd/nriddiford-cnvPlotteR-3f9164e'  \
  --library='/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library' --install-tests 

* installing *source* package ‘cnvPlotteR’ ...
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** preparing package for lazy loading
Warning: Installed Rcpp (0.12.12) different from Rcpp used to build dplyr (0.12.11).
Please reinstall dplyr to avoid random crashes or undefined behavior.
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Warning: Installed Rcpp (0.12.12) different from Rcpp used to build dplyr (0.12.11).
Please reinstall dplyr to avoid random crashes or undefined behavior.
* DONE (cnvPlotteR)
```

I'm using RStudio, which normally autocompletes when typing functions that are loaded. However, I can't see any of the functions, and when I try and run one (for example `plot.chrom()`) I get the following error:

`Error in plot.chrom() : could not find function "plot.chrom"`

Am I doing something wrong? Is this related to the `Please reinstall dplyr to avoid random crashes or undefined behaviour` error? If so, how can I go about fixing that?

---

Edit:

Here's my session info - it appears that it's not installing properly:

```
> session_info()
Session info -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
 system   x86_64, darwin15.6.0        
 ui       RStudio (1.0.143)           
 language (EN)                        
 collate  en_GB.UTF-8                 
 tz       XXX                
 date     2017-07-20                  

Packages -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package    * version    date       source                             
 assertthat   0.2.0      2017-04-11 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                     
 backports    1.1.0      2017-05-22 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                     
 base       * 3.4.1      2017-07-07 local                              
 commonmark   1.2        2017-03-01 cran (@1.2)                        
 compiler     3.4.1      2017-07-07 local                              
 crayon       1.3.2      2016-06-28 cran (@1.3.2)                      
 curl         2.7        2017-06-26 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                     
 datasets   * 3.4.1      2017-07-07 local                              
 desc         1.1.0      2017-01-27 cran (@1.1.0)                      
 devtools   * 1.13.2     2017-06-02 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                     
 digest       0.6.12     2017-01-27 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                     
 git2r        0.18.0     2017-01-01 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                     
 graphics   * 3.4.1      2017-07-07 local                              
 grDevices  * 3.4.1      2017-07-07 local                              
 httr         1.2.1      2016-07-03 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                     
 magrittr     1.5        2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                     
 memoise      1.1.0      2017-04-21 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                     
 methods    * 3.4.1      2017-07-07 local                              
 R6           2.2.2      2017-06-17 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                     
 Rcpp         0.12.12    2017-07-15 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                     
 roxygen2     6.0.1.9000 2017-07-19 Github (klutometis/roxygen@14eae41)
 rprojroot    1.2        2017-01-16 cran (@1.2)                        
 rstudioapi   0.6        2016-06-27 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                     
 stats      * 3.4.1      2017-07-07 local                              
 stringi      1.1.5      2017-04-07 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                     
 stringr      1.2.0      2017-02-18 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                     
 tools        3.4.1      2017-07-07 local                              
 utils      * 3.4.1      2017-07-07 local                              
 withr        1.0.2      2016-06-20 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                     
 xml2         1.1.1      2017-01-24 cran (@1.1.1)
```

Comment: Have you attached it?

Comment: @Hugh - not to my knowledge - how do I do that, and what does it do?

Comment: Sorry, jargon. Have you run `library(cnvPlotteR)` and tried a function in your package?

Comment: Ah, `library(cnvPlotteR)` makes it show up in my `session_info()` but I still can't access the functions

Comment: You need to add more detail: when you say 'access' what do you mean? (Edit your question to show what functions you tried, what you expected would happen, and what actually happened.)

Comment: @Hugh I've updated the question to include an example error message I get from trying one of the functions. I'm using RStudio, which shows me what functions I have available as I type - none of the functions from my package are shown.

Comment: Can you run `file.cleanR`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend Hadley's [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/) and [R Packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/) for more reading on various R topics related to programming and packages.  Lots of good information and answers in there.

**EDIT:** With regard to your edit and looking at `github` - the function you are trying to use has not been exported.  You correctly put the `@export` tag on your docs, but you did not regenerate the `NAMESPACE` file (c.f.):

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

S3method(plot,all.grid) 
S3method(plot,chrom) 
S3method(plot,region)
export(clean_theme) 
export(file.cleanR) 
import(dplyr) 
import(ggplot2) 
import(scales)
import(RColorBrewer)
```

**EDIT2:** The functions that are not being exported all contain `.` (e.g. `plot.all.grid`) and roxygen is anticipating an S3 method because of the `.`, so you've happened onto a common naming convention no-no. See OO or naming conventions. The `@method` tag or some other within roxygen may help disambiguate if you need to include the `.`

**Solution** = Rename functions to exclude `.`, e.g. change `plot.all.grid` to `plotAllGrid`

Comment: Also recommend using [`packrat`](https://rstudio.github.io/packrat/) and many other [`Rstudio` packages](https://www.rstudio.com/), as it will make package development (and controlling versions of your dependencies) easier.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it doesn't work for me. Running `install.packages('dplyr')` seems to work fine, and restarts my session. When I install my package from GitHub I have exactly the same problem as before (and it still installs with `Warning: Installed Rcpp (0.12.12) different from Rcpp used to build dplyr (0.12.11).
Please reinstall dplyr to avoid random crashes or undefined behavior.`

Comment: And when I run `ls('package:cnvPlotteR')` I see only two packages have been loaded: 
`[1] "clean_theme" "file.cleanR"`

Comment: See my edit - you have only exported those two functions and need to re-roxygenize your package docs.  As to your `dplyr` issue (which is probably unrelated), try: `install.packages('dplyr',dependencies=TRUE)` which will force install dependencies.  Perhaps that way you can get aligned `Rcpp` and `dplyr` versions.

Comment: `roxygen2::roxygenize()` from within my package directory does the trick. Where in my workflow should I be using it? Does this need to be done every time I (or someone else) downloads my package from Github?

Comment: @fugu - No, `roxygen2::roxygenize()` or `devtools::document()` should be done whenever you finish additional development (it updates your `NAMESPACE` file and documentation) - before pushing to `github` / etc.  The user should not have to worry about it.  See [documentation](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html) and [NAMESPACE](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html) in the book I referenced.  You can also create hooks to do the call for you - probably a more advanced topic - check out some other packages on `github` for more info.

Comment: I'm still having trouble with this. I've already been using `devtools::document()` after every change, but the NAMESPACE still lists the plot functions as `S3method`s. They are also incorrectly named in the NAMESPACE: e.g. `S3method(plot,all.grid)` should be `S3method(plot.all.grid) ` (comma removed).

Comment: Renaming my functions (e.g. from `plot.region` to `regionPlot`) has allowed them to be listed as exports in NAMESPACE.

Comment: You've got it - `roxygen` is anticipating an S3 method because of the ".", so you've happened onto a common naming convention no-no.  See [OO](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html) or [naming conventions](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/style.html).  The `@method` tag or some other within `roxygen` may help disambiguate if you need to include the "."

Comment: OK thanks for all the info - I'm going to edit your answer to add in your last comment